# IE flash video display:none issue

Tags: flash

Hi i have a video in a facebox window that i am trying to get working. it works in firefox,chrome,safari, but guess what it does not work in IE. from my searching it seems that IE will not play flash content when in a div display:none.

Does anybody know a solution to get flash video to play within a display:none?

I can supply code if needed........I found this solution but does not seem to help: [Loading an FLV in Facebox with jQuery for IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056589/loading-an-flv-in-facebox-with-jquery-for-ie7-and-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

In IE flash is blocked if it's in an element with the style `display:none;`. One method around this wait for the flash file to load (via a timeout), then hiding the element as desired.

Alternatively, you can also write the flash code into the element when you show the element.

However, the best method is to hide the element by adding the style:

```
width:0px; height: 0px; overflow:hidden;
```